# How to find the number of objects or array in a JSON data using jsonCpp

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

My primary need  is how to find the number of elements in top level data.

Given the json data:

```
{
 [
  {Key11:Value11,Key12:Value12,...Key1N:Value1N},
  {Key21:Value21,Key22:Value22,...Key2N:Value2n},
  {Key31:Value31,Key32:Value32,...Key3N:Value3N},
  {Key41:Value41,Key42:Value42,...Key4N:Value4N},
  .
  .
  .
  KeyZ1:ValueZ1,KeyZ2:ValueZ2,...KeyZN:ValueZN}
 ]
}
```

how do I find the number of array elements in the Json data?

Also, given the jason data:

```
{
 {Key11:Value11,Key12:Value12,...Key1N:Value1N}
}
```

How do I find the number of key-value elements in the json data?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `size` member function of a `Json::Value` object, like so. Your data wasn't workable, so I got some from somewhere else but I think you'll see the commonalities.

The `json` data you posted is not syntactically correct. To make it valid you must either name the list element or remove the outer `{}`. I have provided solutions for both possibilities

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

#include "json/json.h"

using namespace std;

void named()
{
    string txt = "{                 \
    \"employees\": [{               \
        \"firstName\": \"John\",    \
        \"lastName\": \"Doe\"       \
    }, {                            \
        \"firstName\": \"Anna\",    \
        \"lastName\": \"Smith\"     \
    }, {                            \
        \"firstName\": \"Peter\",   \
        \"lastName\": \"Jones\"     \
    }]                              \
    }";


    Json::Value root;
    Json::Reader reader;

    bool ok = reader.parse(txt, root, false);

    if(! ok) 
    {
        cout << "failed parse\n";
        return;
    }

    cout << "parsed ok\n";

    // Answer to question 1
    cout << "The employee list is size " << root["employees"].size() << '\n';

    for(const auto& jv: root["employees"])
    {
        // Answer to your second question
        cout << "employee " << jv["firstName"] << " has " << jv.size() << " elements\n";
    }
}

void unnamed()
{
    string txt2 = "[{               \
        \"firstName\": \"John\",    \
        \"lastName\": \"Doe\"       \
    }, {                            \
        \"firstName\": \"Anna\",    \
        \"lastName\": \"Smith\"     \
    }, {                            \
        \"firstName\": \"Peter\",   \
        \"lastName\": \"Jones\"     \
    }]";

    Json::Value root;
    Json::Reader reader;

    bool ok = reader.parse(txt2, root, false);

    if(! ok) 
    {
        cout << "failed parse\n";
        return;
    }

    cout << "parsed ok\n";

    // Answer to question 1
    cout << "The employee list is size " << root.size() << '\n';

    for(const auto& jv: root)
    {
        // Answer to your second question
        cout << "employee " << jv["firstName"] << " has " << jv.size() << " elements\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    named();
    unnamed();
}
```

Comment: So, suppose your samlejson data does not have the employee label.Suppose it simply starts by listing the first na

Comment: is that valid json?

Comment: Its valid if you remove the outer set of `{}`.

Comment: So, suppose your samlejson data does not have the employee label.Suppose it simply starts by listing the first names and surnames.Or is that not allowed.How to tacke suchis the aim of .y quest. I actually already know the soution to the example you ga e. If you remove the label employee label and just list the key:value as array. How would the solution be.

Comment: Did you try my updated answer? You simply need to call size on whichever node you want the size of. If you go with the array only option then the array is the root node itself.

Comment: Ok.If one removes the outer {} and the employee label, how will the solution be.

Comment: Istead of root["employee].size(), what will it be now?

Comment: Please,just one more thing.Would it make sense for  me  to list the elements of a list with numerical idices like root[1] ?

Comment: Did you try it? Check the docs for an `operator[]` overload. I suspect it probably does for an array/list but not a dictionary like item.

Comment: OK.I'll do that.Thanks.